# Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: heroku, rubygems

I am having a problem with pushing my rails project back up to heroku. I was able to do this a few days ago. I made a few changes to my files and tried to re push using `git push heroku`. It starts the process then gives me these errors.

```
> Counting objects: 56, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Writing objects: 100% (37/37), 3.96 KiB, done.
Total 37 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)

`-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
       Installing rake (0.9.2.2) 
       Installing ZenTest (4.7.0) /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:170:in `install': ZenTest requires RubyG
ems version ~> 1.8. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself. (Gem::InstallError)
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

`To git@heroku.com:mbartonsampleapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mbartonsampleapp.git'
```

My Gem fils has

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


gem 'heroku'

group :development do
  gem "ZenTest", "~> 4.7.0"
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

group :production do
# gems specifically for Heroku go here  
   gem 'pg'

end
group :test do
gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
gem 'rspec-rails',  '2.9.0'
gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
gem "spork",  '0.9.0'

end
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
   gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
   gem 'execjs'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Your `Gemfile` looks a bit messed up: the `assets` group isn’t closed (missing `end`), so your `production` and `test` groups are effectively nested in it. (there’s an extra `end` after `gem 'uglifier'` that eventually closes it).

Comment: That worked!!. I cleaned it up. Thanks for you help..

Comment: Great! I’ve made my comment an answer so you can accept it if you want and this question will get marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Gemfile` looks a bit messed up: the `assets` group isn’t closed (it’s missing an `end`), so your `production` and `test` groups are nested in it (there’s an extra `end` after `gem 'uglifier'` that eventually closes it).

This could be confusing Bundler, so that it doesn’t see `ZenTest` as being in the `development` group and tries to install it on Heroku.